# Convergent cameras stitching

Tags: computer-vision, video

I am currently working on a computer vision problem that involve 8 convergent cameras.
I am trying to recreate a 2D image (I actually don't care of the shape of the image) that is the representation of my scene seen from the 8 convergent cameras (like an above view ?).

I am currently working with [*Real-time Stereo-Image Stitching using GPU-based Belief Propagation* by Adam, Jung, Roth and Brunnett](http://vmv09.tu-bs.de/downloads/papers/ada09.pdf),
which has been made for divergent aligned cameras. I am actually working on translating the formulas for not aligned cameras, but I have no clue on how it is going to work with convergent cameras.

I did some researches but didn't find anything on how to do exactly what I want, even if it seems possible.

If you have any path I could explore or any clue, I would love to have them!

I found [*Computer Vision: Algorithms and Applications* by Richard Szeliski](http://szeliski.org/Book/drafts/SzeliskiBook_20100903_draft.pdf) and it actually gives some clues.